# Constrain Layout : Defining Seekbar height with respect to other fields

Tags: android-constraintlayout, android-seekbar

I am adding a couple of Textviews and a Seekbar in a Constraint Layout. I have defined textview height according to the screen height and want the seekbar height to go from one textview to the other. The code is

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailTaskHighTextId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"
                android:text="High"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailTaskLowTextId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75"
                android:text="Low"/>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/detailTaskPriorityId"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="3"
                android:progress="3"
                android:rotation="270"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/detailTaskLowTextId"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/detailTaskHighTextId"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/detailTaskHighTextId"/>
```

I don't want to hardcode the seekbar width. The seekbar width is really small here. Using the Top_toTopOf and Bottom_toBottomOf just brings seekbar in the middle of the two text views. I tried Start_toStart and End_toEnd as well. What am I missing? This is what I am seeing [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBoGl.jpg)

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Standard SeekBar is not designed for vertical usage. Try this instead. https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-verticalseekbar

Answer (score 0):

You need to change height (using MATCH_CONSTRAINT) of seek bar like this:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/detailTaskPriorityId"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp" <- MATCH_CONSTRAINT
    android:max="3"
    android:progress="3"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/detailTaskLowTextId"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/detailTaskHighTextId"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/detailTaskHighTextId"/>
```

Comment: `<- MATCH_CONSTRAINT` it was the comment, just remove it